# Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl. Failing test in Chapter 8.29

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am a newbie working through Hartl. Got to the end of Chapter 8 and when I check my browser for the sign in/sign out every things seems AOK. However when I run this test:

```
$ bundle exec spec spec/
```

returns

```
sis-macbook-pro:sample_app Lagaspi$ bundle exec rspec spec/ 
..............................F

Failures:

1) User pages signup with valid information after saving the user 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Sign out') }
   expected link "Sign out" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:48:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.60715 seconds
31 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:48 # User pages signup with valid information after saving the user
```

I have an idea but i'm not exactly sure. So here's my user_pages_spec.rb file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

subject { page }

describe "signup page" do
before { visit signup_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
end

describe "profile page" do
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before { visit user_path(user) }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
end

describe "signup" do

before { visit signup_path }

let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

describe "with invalid information" do
it "should not create a user" do
expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
end
end

describe "with valid information" do
before do
fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
  end

it "should create a user" do
expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
  end

  describe "after saving the user" do
before { click_button submit }
it { should have_link('Sign out') }
  end
 end
end
end
```

Comment: capybara has a method called save_and_open_page that you can insert before "it" that will open the page as the test runner sees it. Makes debugging things like this a bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up?version=3.2#code-after_save_tests, and add those lines into you spec.

Answer (score 0):

could you post your view file? Without it, it's difficult to tell what's wrong. From what I'm seeing, it only says you don't have the link.

Comment: Sorry views file? Where is that?

Comment: Sorry don't understand the capybara comment either! Im new to all this!

Comment: Please can someone help here?

Comment: Please can someone explain what this view file is and where it is located? This is very confusing!

Comment: view file - Do you mean views/layouts/application.html.erb ?

Comment: To summarize:  Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Sign out') }
   expected link "Sign out" to return something

checks if your web pages shows a link to the "Sign out" page. The failure indicates it doesn't (probably you haven't added it yet).
You can even check this *normally*, i.e. using your web browser and logging in.

Comment: application.html.erb is the general layout of the application. You should have something else in the /view directory.

Comment: OK thanks. I can understand where the error has come from now.